# Error in Python Dictionary when updating without reference

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a following dictionary (nested):

```
d = {'q0': {'VB': 2, 'NN': 8}, 'VB': {'DT': 5, 'NN': 3, 'IN': 2}}
```

My Goal is to update the values present in the above dictionary to probabilities. That is calculated as `P(VB|q0) = count of verb/total count of q0`
Thus **P(VB|q0) = 2/10** from the given dictionary. After similar calculation of every key my new dictionary should look like

```
d_new = {'q0': {'VB': 0.2, 'NN': 0.8}, 'VB': {'DT': 0.5, 'NN': 0.3, 'IN': 0.2}}
```

Now the code I wrote to implement above is as follows:

```
d = {'q0': {'VB': 2, 'NN': 8}, 'VB': {'DT': 5, 'NN': 3, 'IN': 2}}
d_new = {}
d_new.update(d)
for key in d.keys():
    for i in d[key].keys():
        d_new[key][i] = d[key][i]/ float(sum(d[key].values()))
```

This gives me the result as:

```
{'q0': {'VB': 0.2, 'NN': 0.9756097560975611}, 'VB': {'DT': 0.5, 'NN': 0.5454545454545454, 'IN': 0.6567164179104478}}
```

I am assuming that the original d is also getting updated. To prevent this I used **update()**. But it does not seem to work. How can I get the desired result?

Comment: Look into `copy.deepcopy`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was not aware of the existing question. I tried but could not find anything on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `deepcopy`

```
d_new = copy.deepcopy(d)
```